# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class в PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь зайти на сайт по адресу **login.php**, но выскакивает вот такая ошибка:

> **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Generator in /var/www/GameEngine/Generator.php on line 12**

Перехожу в файл Generator.php и на 12 строке вижу такой PHP код:

```
class Generator {
```

В файле login.php пока-что не смог найти где подключается или вызывается файл Generator.php...

Как мне победить эту ошибку?

0
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class в PHP
54
eprivalov
16 минут назад
Добрый день.

Пытаюсь зайти на сайт travianx5.ru/login.php, но выскакивает вот такая ошибка:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Generator in /var/www/GameEngine/Generator.php on line 12

Перехожу в файл Generator.php и на 12 строке вижу такой PHP код:

class Generator {

В файле login.php пока-что не смог найти где подключается или вызывается файл Generator.php...

**UPD:** Такая ошибка возникает если зайти на страницу регистрации. На обеих страницах вначале есть такой код:

```
include('GameEngine/Account.php');
```

Я правильно понимаю, что его лучше изменить на функцию `require_once()`?

**UPD2:** Стоит ли все функции `include()` заменить на функции `require_once()` в файлах login.php и в файле регистрации?

Comment: Вы пробовали переводить текст ошибки ?  
Переименуйте класс или используйте [PHP:namespaces](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: вы обновили php до версии >=5.5 

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php

придется переименовать свой класс.

Comment: да, у меня стоит версия PHP 5.5.3! А теперь я понимаю в чем проблема... Но возможно проще будет использовать namespace?

Comment: ну это как удобнее (смотря какого размера ваш проект), неймспейс мне кажется сложнее организовать чем поиск с заменой, типа такого:

    find . -iname '*.php' -exec 'perl' '-pi' '-e' 's/Generator/MyGenerator/g' '{}' '+'

Comment: В проекте множество вот таких строк кода 

`$act = $generator->generateRandStr(10);`

Т.е. мне нужно изменить название класса Generator и переменной $generator везде в проекте? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: `$generator` можно юзать, главное изменить строки типа `new Generator` и название класса конечно.
типа было

   $generator=new Generator();

а стало

   $generator=new MyGenerator();

Comment: А нужно ли менять самую первую строку, где объявляется класс?

class Generator {
....
}

Comment: да конечно, (MyGenerator это конечно пример, лучше что нить ближе к контексту)

Comment: ок, спасибо за помощь, сейчас буду пробовать и позже напишу результат - получилось или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, помогло переименование класса.