# Дебаг приложения на PHP

Tags: php

Доброй ночи, поздравляю всех с новым 2014 годом!

Я уже не один раз задавал вопросы о проекте, который мне доверили - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284768/php-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284552/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284516/php-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-warning-%D0%BE%D0%B2) и вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284493/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-%D0%B2-php).

Обрисую проблему - когда заходим на [login.php](http://travianx5.ru/login.php) или на страницу [регистрации](http://travianx5.ru/anmelden.php), то видим одинаковые предупреждения:

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2834
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 905
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4006
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4196
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 1042
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4006**

Но если попытаться зайти в игру, то увидим такие ошибки:

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2834

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 905

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4006

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4196

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 1042

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Automation.php on line 4006

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 76

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 206

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 225

Connect Error (0)**

Вот так начинается код класса:

```
class MYSQLi_DB {

    var $connection;

    function MYSQL_DB() {       
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(SQL_SERVER, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_DB) or die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Вот кусок кода, где происходит ошибка Connect Error (0):

```
function sitterLogin($username, $password) {
        $q = "SELECT sit1,sit2 FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "users WHERE username = '$username' AND access != " . BANNED;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
        $dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); //ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
        if($dbarray['sit1'] != 0) {
            $q2 = "SELECT password FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . $dbarray['sit1'] . " AND access != " . BANNED;
            $result2 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q2);
            $dbarray2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
        if($dbarray['sit2'] != 0) {
                $q3 = "SELECT password FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "users WHERE id = " . $dbarray['sit2'] . " AND access != " . BANNED;
                $result3 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q3);
                $dbarray3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
        if($dbarray['sit1'] != 0 || $dbarray['sit2'] != 0) {
            if($dbarray2['password'] == md5($password) || $dbarray3['password'] == md5($password)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Как улучшить код? Как избавиться от предупреждений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из справки по `mysqli_query` [тынц](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

> Возвращает FALSE в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN `mysqli_query()` вернет объект `mysqli_result`. Для остальных успешных запросов `mysqli_query()` вернет TRUE.

У вас запрос возвращает false и вы пытаетесь затем "распарсить" результат. Сделайте проверку, что запрос отработал корректно

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
if ($result){
    $dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); 
    ...........
```